# Special character Excel import

Tags: android, import

i have a problem with importing data from an excel file.

It works well, but in this file are words with the german letters "ä", "ö", "ü" and "ß".

When i import these words, i get these strange characters: �

Any plan how to convert them into the right characters?!

Thanks,
prexx

Comment: What do you use to import excel file? Android or java cannot read xls files directly.

Comment: i use the jxl.jar libary and used the code shown here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html (example to read from file)

Comment: try `wbSettings.setEncoding("CP1252")`, or ISO-8859-2 or UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Workbook like this:

```
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setEncoding("CP1252");
w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook, wbSettings);
```