# import excel file with subscript character

Tags: php, mysql, excel, subscript

Uploading Excel file is ok and not an issue

gone through many articles on uloading excel to mysql
Tried

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889220/1026905 (really nice encoding class)

MY issue is i cannot upload  the chracter seen in excel file  as it is

superscript part is getting converted 
Example in

`∴ tn = n² + 2n + 1 + 2`

n²   ... gets converted as it is
 ∴   .... get converted as it is

all characters  like ∠Ωπ √ ∞ ≅⊥∫∪∴≈≡⊆μ I could get converted as it is

Only issue is  tn, t1, t2, t3  i am unable to get n,1,2,3 as subscript (cannot be displayed here but you can view in the image

```
 tn ... should be t<sub>n</sub>

... in html format n should be subscript
```

I am not  getting this as it is

Comment: The superscripted character is probably rich text, using superscript; so use your library's rich text handling features to read it

Comment: Dear Mark Pls guide me how to use " use your library's rich text handling features to read it"

Answer (score 2):

Using PHPExcel, you can identify if a cell contains rich text because a getValue() call will return a PHPExcel_RichText object rather than a string/integer/float/boolean scalar type.

You can then loop through the collection of PHPExcel_RichText_Run objects for that PHPExcel_RichText object looking at the style associated with it:

```
$cellValueAsString = '';
$elements = $cell->getValue()->getRichTextElements();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    // Rich text start?
    if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) {
        if ($element->getFont()->getSuperScript()) {
            $cellValueAsString .= '<sup>';
        } else if ($element->getFont()->getSubScript()) {
            $cellValueAsString .= '<sub>';
        }
    }
    // Convert UTF8 data to PCDATA
    $cellText = $element->getText();
    $cellValueAsString .= htmlspecialchars($cellText);
    if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) {
        if ($element->getFont()->getSuperScript()) {
            $cellValueAsString .= '</sup>';
        } else if ($element->getFont()->getSubScript()) {
            $cellValueAsString .= '</sub>';
        }
    }
}
```

would be a simple block of code to turn the rich text cell content into simple HTML markup showing superscripted and subscripted characters

Comment: Thanks  $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue(); is the cell value I am getting I tried  $elements = $cell->getValue()->getRichTextElements();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    // Rich text start? but getting error Call to a member function getRichTextElements() on a non-object in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\maratheclasses\PHPexcel_178\php178reader.php on line 27

Comment: You need to check if the value returned from the $val = $cell->getValue(); call is a rich text object before parsing it in this way; if you're just getting a normal scalar returned (e.g the cell value is a simple numeric) then you will get this error if you try to parse it as rich text

Comment: I had included PHPExcel/cell/DataType.php and tried command echo "<br>find data type :".dataTypeForValue($val); but getting error Call to undefined function dataTypeForValue() in... humble request pls guide which class to include and hot ot get value returned from  $val = $cell->getValue();

Comment: I tried examples in directory  Documentation/Examples/     it seems i am not getting proper way .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code to read text with superscript from excel file using PHPExcel.

```
`/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel2007 file" , EOL;
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("Book5.xlsx");

 echo date('H:i:s') , " Iterate worksheets by Row" , EOL;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle() , EOL;
     
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        echo '    Row number - ' , $row->getRowIndex() , EOL;

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if (!is_null($cell)   ) { 
                
                $orginaltext = $cell->getValue() ;
                  if (is_object($orginaltext)) {
                    $cellValueAsString = '';
                    $cellValueAsString1 = '';
                
                 if ($orginaltext->getRichTextElements() ) { 
                    $elements = $cell->getValue()->getRichTextElements();

                foreach ($elements as $element) {
                    if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) { 
                        
                        if ($element->getFont()->getSuperScript()) {
                            
                            $cellValueAsString .= '<sup>';
                        } else if ($element->getFont()->getSubScript()) {
                            $cellValueAsString .= '<sub>';
                        }
                        
                        $cellText = $element->getText();
                        $cellValueAsString .= htmlspecialchars($cellText);
                        
                        if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) {
                            
                            if ($element->getFont()->getSuperScript()) {
                                
                                $cellValueAsString .= '</sup>';
                            } else if ($element->getFont()->getSubScript()) {
                                $cellValueAsString .= '</sub>';
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        $cellText = $element->getText();
                        $cellValueAsString .= htmlspecialchars($cellText);
                    }
                    
                }
                 echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ' , nl2br($cellValueAsString) , EOL;
                     
                } 
                 }
                 else{
                echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ' , nl2br($cell->getCalculatedValue()) , EOL;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
 `
```

Also you can use the below code to get specific cell from Excel instead of row iteration.
$cell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11,2);  This can be used to select purticular row.