# How do I import Subscript and Superscript from an excel file to mySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, database

We have a lot of chemistry MCQs in an excel file with lot of chemistry formulas and equations. When we tried to import these MCQs into mySQL based database all subscripts used in formulas lost and taken as normal character e.g, H2SO4, CO2, CH3 etc and makes our formulas and elements name nonsense. 
Is there any solution by which mySQL can import subscript and superscript as it is from excel?
Or Is there any solution so we can force excel to consider subscript and superscript as inserted symbols because mySQL can pick symbols as it is?

Comment: I think in Excel those numbers really are just normal numbers, formatted as superscript and subscript. They aren't different characters, are they?

Comment: It looks like the answer here may show a way to do it with PhpExcel (PhpSpreadsheet now): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544042/import-excel-file-with-subscript-character

Comment: You will need to store the information in 'formatted' state. Seems to me that HTML might somehow be your route forward here?

Comment: Good idea @MandyShaw - export the file as HTML and parse it into the database as required.

Comment: Tried all but all fails to solve my problem, looking some script or solution to replace all sub script or super script with excel symbols